# function to clear textarea on focus and removeChild

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to clear the textarea once the user clicks it, here's my current method for this

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Nxg2/

```
<textarea type="text" id="address" 
          onfocus="if(this.value===this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Input Address Here</textarea>
```

however, I want another event/function to occur when the user clicks the textarea, which is this one,

```
  function removeImage(){
  selected =  document.getElementById("country").value;
  display = false;
  document.getElementById("country").value = "";
  selected = null;    
  var MyContainer = document.getElementById("container");
  MyContainer.removeChild(MyContainer.childNodes[0])
  {
```

so I tried this one, but it did'nt work how can I make the other event work when the user clicks the textarea:

```
<textarea type="text" id="address" onfocus="removeImage()"
              onfocus="if(this.value===this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Input Address Here</textarea>
```

Comment: Are you sure about jQuery?

Comment: @Satpal not quite sure it was recommended by SO for the tags

Comment: If you don't want solution is jQuery remove the tag

Comment: Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SmokeyPHP/3Nxg2/2/) - it's better to assign event handlers with javascript rather than element properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onFocus(){
  document.getElementById("address").value = "";
  document.getElementById("res").value = "Results will be displayed here";
  document.getElementById("valid").value = "";
  document.getElementById("valid2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("cor").value = "Changes will be displayed here";
  document.getElementById("street_number").value = "";
  document.getElementById("route").value = "";
  document.getElementById("locality").value = "";
  document.getElementById("administrative_area_level_1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("country").value = "";
  document.getElementById("postal_code").value = "";

  selected =  document.getElementById("country").value;
  display = false;
  document.getElementById("country").value = "";
  selected = null;    
  var MyContainer = document.getElementById("container");
  MyContainer.removeChild(MyContainer.childNodes[0]);

  map.setCenter(defaultLatLng);
  map.setZoom(0);
  marker.setMap(null);

  }

<textarea type="text" id="address" onclick="onFocus()">Input Address Here
</textarea>
```

figured I could do something like this, tnx for the ideas guys, posting it maybe for others who have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<textarea type="text" id="address" onfocus="removeImage(); if(this.value===this.defaultValue)this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value==='')this.value=this.defaultValue">Input Address Here</textarea>
```

(combining the two `onfocus` attributes, otherwise the second one would overwrite the first one)

Comment: I am sure you can provide a better solution(Please provide an example with event binding)